# How to move text below to icon in SegmentedButtons

Tags: react-native-paper

I want to custom-style the SegmentedButtons from react-native-paper library
I tried the following code that works

```
<SegmentedButtons
  value={value}
  onValueChange={setValue}
  density="medium"
  theme={{ roundness: 0 }}
  buttons={[
    {
      value: "walk",
      label: "Walking",
      style: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      value: "train",
      label: "Transit",
      style: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      value: "drive",
      label: "Driving",
      style: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
  ]}
/>;
```

But how do I push text to below the icon ?